# data from two tables without join

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Table "subjects" contains columns:

```
sub_date, sub_content, student_id
2014-10-03, english, 1
2014-10-09, maths, 2
2014-10-11, biology, 1
```

and
Table games contains columns:

```
game_date, game_content, student_id
2014-10-05, Hockey, 1
2014-10-18, Tennis, 1
2014-10-20, Cricket, 2
```

I want to display all details of student_id 1 order by date (considering both sub_date and game_date

```
Date, Topic
2014-10-03, english
2014-10-05, Hockey
2014-10-11, biology
2014-10-18, Tennis
```

Please help

Comment: What do you have against joins?

Comment: there is no common row that join both tables. thats why...

Comment: What about `student_id`?

Comment: it should be in WHERE clause

Comment: You can use the same column in both clauses (JOIN-ON, WHERE)

Comment: Please paste your code here

Comment: Try this: `SELECT [cols] FROM subjects LEFT JOIN games on subjects.student_id = games.student_id`

Comment: it will display different usersdata ie student_id 1 & 2. I need to display only one student's data

Comment: Yeah, obviously. If you want to limit the results to a specific row, you need to put that in the `WHERE` clause. Like `WHERE student_id = x`. And if you couldn't figure even that out by yourself, you would be much better learning the basics of MySQL.

Comment: there is noneed of "on subjects.student_id = games.student_id". Because I dont need to display columns of both table in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
select sub_date,sub_content from subjects where student_id = 1
UNION
select game_date,topic from games where student_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this (even though sounds not such as a good idea):

```
SELECT tmp.sub_date AS Date,tmp.sub_content AS Topic 
FROM (
    SELECT sub_date,sub_content,student_id FROM subjects 
    UNION SELECT game_date,game_content,student_id FROM games
) tmp 
WHERE tmp.student_id = 1 ORDER BY tmp.sub_date;
```